# Python Pandas Dataframe update values efficently

Tags: python, performance, pandas, dataframe

which is the fastest way to achieve the following:

I'm using a Pandas Dataframe (NxN) and i want to iterate over each row and each element to check if the element is greater than the rows mean. If it is greater i want to change the element value to 1.

I calculate the mean value using :

```
mean_value = df.ix[elementid].mean(axis=0)
```

but iterating over each element and checking if it is >= mean_value with a nested loop is really slow.

Comment: You are accessing  every element, what makes you think you can do better than O(nm).

Comment: I'm just hoping there is function in pandas to apply the value 1 row-wise if the elements are greater than the mean

Comment: That function would do exactly the same thing as doing it by hand. You are changing every element of the array, therefore you have to access every element of the array. You can't do it faster

Comment: I'm doing the loops in python and i thought pandas is partly written in cython or based on libraries which are written in cython and therefore would be faster

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can first count [`mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mean.html) by rows, then comparing with [`ge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ge.html) and where [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) add `1`:

```
print df
   a  b  c
0  0  1  2
1  0  1  2
2  1  1  2
3  1  0  1
4  1  1  2
5  0  0  1

mean_value = df.mean(axis=1)
print mean_value
0    1.000000
1    1.000000
2    1.333333
3    0.666667
4    1.333333
5    0.333333

mask = df.ge(mean_value, axis=0)
print mask
       a      b     c
0  False   True  True
1  False   True  True
2  False  False  True
3   True  False  True
4  False  False  True
5  False  False  True
print df.mask(mask, 1)
   a  b  c
0  0  1  1
1  0  1  1
2  1  1  1
3  1  0  1
4  1  1  1
5  0  0  1
```

Comment: That was neat use of `mask` and `ge`!

Comment: very elegant solution +1

Comment: Looks good except for final result.  Don't you just want `df.mask(df.gt(df.mean(axis=1)), 1)`?

Comment: Glad can help you! Good luck!